# nopCommerce 4.0 Widgets error - The page you requested was not found

Tags: routes, widget, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

I have created a Widget in nopCommerce_4.00, and could see/install in Admin area. But when I click Configure button, it navigates to URL - `http://localhost:15536/Admin/WidgetsProductMessage/Configure`
And the error is - `The page you requested was not found`

I created ViewComponent and used in widgetZone, but that too gives error - A view component named 'WidgetsProductMessage' could not be found.

Any idea where the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: I recreated using Nivo Slider project and it worked